# Enable plugins in VIM. E492: Not an editor command: PlugInstall

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vimrc

I've been following [this video tutorial,](https://youtu.be/zE0hno3vV9M) to install some VIM plugins in order to change the text colors in my VIM editor, especially to make comments brighter color.

I've created `.vimrc` file. It looks like this:

```
  1
  2 set nocompatible     " Set compatibility to Vim only
  3
  4 set number    " Show line numbers
  5
  6 set wrap    " Automatically wrap text that extends beyond the screen length
  7
  8 set laststatus=2    " Show status bar
  9
 10 set encoding=utf-8     " Force encoding
 11
 12 " Call the .vimrc.plug file
 13 if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.plug"))
 14        source "~/.vimrc.plug"
 15 endif
 16
 17 ":inoremap <Caps> <Esc>
 18 ":inoremap <Caps_Lock> <Esc>
 19 ":inoremap <CapsLock> <Esc>
 20
```

I've created `.vimrc.plug` file. It looks like this:

```
  1 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  2
  3 "Fugitive Vim Github Wrapper
  4 Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
  5
  6 call plug#end()
```

Later I've executed command:

```
sudo curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Yes. I've checked I have `git` installed.

I've opened `vim` and gave command `:PlugInstall`.

In the output I get `E492: Not an editor command: PlugInstall`.
How to enable those VIM plugins?

I have also got other errors after I've run simple `vim` command:

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ vim
Error detected while processing /home/michal/.vimrc[14]../home/michal/.vimrc.plug:
line    2:
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
line    5:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
line    7:
E117: Unknown function: plug#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your config and you have 2 error in your config

1. for source command you have to pass filepath not string it should be like this example below

```
if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.plug"))
    source ~/.vimrc.plug
endif
```

2. for last problem you said you have its because you ran curl command with sudo. so if you using a normal user like "john" you would have permission problem and `Error detected while processing /home/michal/.vimrc[14]../home/michal/.vimrc.plug:` error for fixing that you have to use curl command without sudo

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Comment: You mean ```if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.plug")) / source ~/.vimrc.plug / endif```. Right?

Comment: yeah thats what i mean im gonna edit my answer